# how do transact the multiple queries in prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

i want to bind the n number of queries through loop and execute the queries in single call. is this possible?

```
   foreach($values as $value){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into tablename (val) values (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$val);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

sample code

```
$valArray = array();
foreach($values as $val)
{
    $valArray[] = "($val)";
}

$valString = implode(',', $valArray);

$stmt = $pdo->query("insert into tablename (val) values $valString");
```